# mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages command getting "command not found" error

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper installed, but when trying to setup an application, I enter `mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages` I get the following error:

`-bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found`

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this. As a beginner, I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to enable `virtualenvwrapper` as described in [its docs](http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/install.html#shell-startup-file).

> Shell Startup File
>
> Add three lines to your shell startup file (`.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc.)
>   to set the location where the virtual environments should live, the
>   location of your development project directories, and the location of
>   the script installed with this package:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs 
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

> After editing it, reload the startup file (e.g., run `source ~/.bashrc`).

Answer (score 4):

This can actually vary a little bit depending on how you installed it. If you installed it on Ubuntu with apt, the virtualenvwrapper functions are actually rolled into a bash completion file (figuring that out was fun!).

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs 
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
possible_scripts='/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper'
for script in $possible_scripts; do
  [[ -f $script ]] && source $script
done
```